# After update Magento > Fatal error: Out of memory

Tags: magento, upgrade, php

After upgrading magento from 1.5.1 to 1.6.1 by ssh I get the next error:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 41418752) (tried to allocate 24768513 bytes) in /home/username/public_html/downloader/lib/Mage/Archive/Abstract.php on line 45
```

I edited my php.ini to:

```
max_execution_time = 18000
max_input_time = 6000
memory_limit = 256M
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?
After trying and searching for a whole day it's getting pretty frustrating.

Any help would be realy appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: And you get the same error as before the changes? If so, try raising your `memory_limit` in the `.htaccess` file of Magento instead of `php.ini`. In standard Magento the `.htaccess` value will overwrite the value you've set in `php.ini`.

Comment: When i change the memorylimit in the .htaccess file i still get the same error. Strange enough the .htaccess file is also reset after doing the upgrade??? So when I raise the .htaccess file to 512m it's reset back to the old values after doing the upgrade.

Comment: Uh, I didn't know that you try to upgrade the PEAR way. Never did this myself. Hm, looking at the `./mage` shell script I'd say changing `memory_limit` in the `php.ini` of what you've set for `MAGE_PHP_BIN` should do. Or setting `-d memory_limit="512M"` in the `exec` line of the shell script.

Answer (score 2):

You're editing the wrong php.ini file.

```
(tried to allocate 24768513 bytes)
```

24768513 bytes is about `24188 KB`, which is about `23 MB`.  Your changes aren't being seen.

Temporarily add a call to

```
phpinfo();
exit;
```

to the top of whatever PHP file is your main entry point.  That's `index.php` for a web context, `mage.php` for Magento Connect context.

This will tell you which `php.ini` file(s) PHP is using, as well as what the runtime values are for all the ini flags.  Edit this file instead.

If you can't edit this file, use the [ini_set](http://php.net/ini_set) function to set a value at runtime.

Comment: Ok, this is going far beyond my knowledge :-(. In index.php and mage.php there is no php.ini line. But thanks for taking time to answer my question ;-). Maybe upgrading magento is not as easy as I though?

Comment: You need to add phpinfo(); to file index.php and then you'll see on any page of your site which of php.ini was used. Don't try to search php.ini line in mage.php ;)

Answer (score 1):

Can you, please, provide an information what concretly you did? (Step by step)

I think you need to change php.ini to:

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

As you see message that

```
(allocated 41418752) (tried to allocate 24768513 bytes)
```

What is the reason of updating by ssh? 
Are there any other cases to update magento?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea how to upgrade otherwise :-/

This is what I Do:

I login
ssh -p 4000 username@31.186.169.4

Than I go to the public html
cd public_html

Change writing permissions:
chmod 700 ./mage

I install the update:
./mage install community Mage_All_Latest